# Camera orientation in Portrait mode in android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

the camera orientation in android with portrait mode gives view with an rotated angle of 90 degrees. 
the link says here as a bug in android and I am using sdk 2.2.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1193

I have tried all the  methods in the link but could not set right the issue. Any answers on this issue would be helpful. Looking forward for your reply. 
thanks.

Comment: Have a look - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259299/force-a-camera-to-always-open-in-portrait-mode-in-android/10259572#10259572

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you are going to use those captured image further . . . 
so if you are going to capture and just display it in an Imageview better rotate it to 90 degree and set the bitmap using the following code

```
public static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap b, int degrees) 
{
    if (degrees != 0 && b != null) 
    {
        Matrix m = new Matrix();

        m.setRotate(degrees, (float) b.getWidth() / 2, (float) b.getHeight() / 2);
        try {
            Bitmap b2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), m, true);
            if (b != b2) 
            {
                b.recycle();
                b = b2;
            }
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError ex) 
        {
           throw ex;
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

or if you are going to save it to the SDcard and use it , after taking picture rotate the bitmap using former code and then save it in sdcard .