# Force a camera to always open in portrait mode in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

Is it possible to open the Camera Intent in android in only portrait  mode, that is even if the user flipped the device, the camera will still be in portrait mode,

I tried the following answer: [Force Portrait Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908387/force-portrait-mode-in-camera) but didn't work, Thanks

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491961/android-capture-photo and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543059/android-camera-in-portrait-on-surfaceview/6762941#6762941

Answer (score 5):

Try it -

```
private void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
         int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
     android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
             new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
     android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
     int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
             .getRotation();
     int degrees = 0;
     switch (rotation) {
         case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
     }

     int result;
     if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
         result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
         result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
     } else {  // back-facing
         result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
     }
     camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
 }

private void initCamera() {
     if(mCamera == null) {
          mCamera = Camera.open();
          setCameraDisplayOrientation(activity, CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, mCamera);
          mCamera.unlock();
      }
}
```

Comment: `cameraID` is only available above API Lv.9. This methods from Google might work for those devices above API Lv.9, for those below 9, a if statement to see if `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` greater than `Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD` is a necessary.

Comment: Worked on API Lv14 and Above, crashed on 2.3.6